# Java HashMap; Is recommendable?

Tags: java, hashmap

It has been reported that from Java JDK 1.3.1 to JDK 1.4.0
HashMap is 5 times slower (see
[here](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4669519)).

What is the state of the art of HashMap at java 6?
Is recommendable to be used?

Thanks.

Comment: at which place you are willing to use it ?

Comment: Why the commentless downvote? This sounds interesting. Thus: +1.

Comment: The question is clear. Is this bug repaired or it is still 5 times slower as in java 1.3.1

Comment: well i was not that down voter

Comment: Luis, almost all of us use HashMaps almost every day. This is a core class that everybody needs all the time and that almost all third party libs use. Don't worry, it works good and it's fast enough.

Comment: It says "fix delivered" in the bug report, does it not? Worrying about bugs fixed 8 years ago strikes me as a singularly useless pastime. Besides, even then it was most emphatically NOT true that HashMap was 5 times slower in general - the problem was in fact caused by a change that made the implementation *faster* in most cases - it just resulted in problems very specific circumstances.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That bug is marked fixed in 1.4.0_02 and 1.4.1, so there probably isn't any need to worry about its performance in Java 1.6.

(If you're in a multithreaded environment, you probably want ConcurrrentHashMap.)

Answer (score 0):

Just for your information , if do not already.the difference between the hashmap and the hashtable is that hashtable is synchronized and does not allow null as key also the main difference is that hashmap has enhanced hash function thAt prevents two different object getting in to single bucket or to prevent Hash collision.

Answer (score 0):

@Suresh
It is not correct to say that HashMap prevents collisions altogether. In fact, in each bucket, there lies an implementation of a singly linked-list of entries. So, collisions do happen in HashMap. I admit I'm not sure about the percentage of collisions as compared to Hashtable.